# Java: try-catch MySQL exception

Tags: java, mysql

I'm encountering errors when connecting to MySQL from Java, so I'm wrapping the connection establishment in a `try` statement. However, doing this means that any attempt to use the `Connection` variable afterwards throws a `variable conn might not have been initialized` error.
What is the proper way to do this?
What I have:

```
Connection conn;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "alexis","pass");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("SQL exception: " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
if (!conn.isClosed()) {
    conn.close();
}
```

Error:

```
> variable conn might not have been initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable con is accessible outside of the try/catch but the compiler is smart enough to recognize that it is possible that con might never be assigned a value, not even null. Local variables are not automatically null like instance variables.
The easiest thing to address that is to change.

```
Connection con;
```

to

```
Connection con = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your object like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
```

And then make sure it's not null before you use it:

```
if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
    conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection conn;  //was declared without initializing any value. You encountered error when try to use an uninitialized connection instance
Connection conn = null; // declared & initialized
```

Code:

```
Connection conn = null;  // initialize conn with null value
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "alexis","pass");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("SQL exception: " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
finally{
    if (conn !=null && !conn.isClosed()) { // validate conn whether it is null 
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use ***try-with-resources*** which can close connection automatically.

```
  try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlStrQuery);){
        // execution code here..
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        // do something
    }
```